# ROS Installation Instructions Broken?

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're trying to install ros on a new system, but during the key setup step, ubuntu is responding with an error claiming

```
wget: unable to resolve host address 'packages.ros.org'
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

This occurs after attempting to execute

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

The same problem came up about a week ago on a different system, but it was fixable using

```
sudo gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv A258828C
```

(Which was scrounged up from the depths of an old wiki post)

However, this no longer works. Before this month, OpenPGP has never appeared during the ros installation process, but is now making it impossible to complete installation. Is there an easy way to resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65623/ros-installation-instructions-broken?/) by [UW NDCL](https://answers.ros.org/users/2777/uw-ndcl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UW NDCL](https://answers.ros.org/users/2777/uw-ndcl/) on 2013-06-20**:
This seems to be the case. For some reason, the system is unable to connect to the network, even on a wired connection.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-22**:
I'm getting issues with `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116` timing out, tried `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116` and get key B01FA116 not found on this server

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-22**:
and as soon as I posted this it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks more like a connection problem. Maybe just trying again at a later time or using a mirror will fix that. I can currently ping packages.ros.org.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0